# selecting a class having a specific class in CSS

Tags: html, css, mathml

```
<math>
 <mfrac class="mfrac_class">
<mstyle class="num_class">
  <mrow>
    <mn>1</mn>
    <mi>a</mi>
  </mrow>
</mstyle>
<mstyle class="den_class">
  <mrow>
    <mi>x</mi>
  </mrow>
</mstyle>
</mfrac>
<mfrac class="mfrac_class">
<mstyle class="num_class">
  <mrow>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mtext class="mtext_class">b</mtext>
  </mrow>
</mstyle>
<mstyle class="den_class">
  <mrow>
    <mn>3</mn>
    <mtext class="mtext_class">c</mtext>
  </mrow>
    </mstyle>
  </mfrac>
</math>
```

I want to apply separate styles for `num_class` and `num_class` **having** `mtext_class`.
I know how to do this in JQuery, but I need any better solution in CSS.

Do not confuse this as invalid HTML, this is Mathml, a part of HTML.

---

**Concluded there is no solution for this in CSS, has to work on in JQuery**

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: What you are describing would require a parent selector, of which there is none in CSS.

Comment: I do not know if this is possible or not?

Comment: thanks for edit ZWord, I tried a lot to format in here. Will learn soon

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed that you want to target the parent element based on child class combination which is not possible using CSS alone, You can use jQuery [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to achieve that...

```
$('ul.num_class').has('li.mtext_class').closest('ul.num_class').css({
    'border':'1px solid #f00'
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nPW7D/)

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood the question. He is looking for a way to style element by their child element classes. This would work if both classes were on the same element.

Comment: this is mathml, which is valid in html

Comment: @madhu_p wasn't aware, but what you are trying to achieve is not possible with css

Comment: @madhu_p MathML =/= HTML, while the former is included in the latter, they are two different specifications, even though similar in markup.

Comment: @Daedalus I agree with you. MathML is different from HTML. But my question is still valid i hope.

Comment: @madhu_p Yes it's completely valid :)

Comment: Ok, as all of you confirms that there is no direct possible solution in CSS as of now, I will use JQuery for solving this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Mr.Alien

Comment: @madhu_p nope, you cannot do that with css as of now, and if this solves, you can just click on the tick beside my answer :)